# if statement in for loop only executing once

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to compare retrieved json data from a database, and there is a nested if statement within the for loop. The problem is that the `'if'` statement is only executing once (when it finds the first record in the database), and then it's being skipped in further iterations.
I am using PHP and MySQL (for the db).

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($obj['datalist']);$i++){
    $name[]=$obj['datalist'][$i]['name'];
    if ($name[$i]===$row['user']){ //once it finds the first record, it goes to the 'else' part for the rest of the for loop
    //if ($row['user']==$name[$i]){
        echo "<p class='testclass'>".$name[$i] ." is in the database! ".$i."<br />";
    } else {
        echo "<p class='testclass'>". $name[$i] ." is NOT in the database! ".$i."</p>";
    }
}
```

Code can be also found [here](http://pastebin.com/Afuh6N6g).

Comment: What's weird is that you're simply pushing the name into the `$name` array without any previously defined indexes and then check for it using `$i` as an index. You sure you shouldn't be doing it like this: `$name[$i]=$obj['datalist'][$i]['name'];`?

Comment: to be honest, this is the first time i've done anything with json, so i have no idea

Comment: Hmm, so you're building an array which you will later output as a JSON string?

Comment: Is this problem solved? please let us know

Answer (score 1):

Should your code not be this:

```
$name=$obj['datalist'][$i]['name'];

//if ($name[$i]===$row['user']){
if ($row['user']==$name){
```

You are already getting the name from the collection, and you want to compare it with your $row isnt?

Answer (score 1):

You are recreating the same $name in every loop.

you should use this line instead :

```
$name[$i]=$obj['datalist'][$i]['name'];
```

Or if you don't need to reuse the $name collection/array then you can simply overwrite it using :

```
$name = $obj['datalist'][$i]['name'];
```

and modify your if statement according to this variable